# Buzzing power supply

Tags: power-supply, power, acoustic-noise

I have a power supply that buzzes when nothing is connected and is silent when there is a power drain. What could it be?

It's a PC power supply that I used to power an LCD through its 12 V line.

Comment: What is the power supply's minimum load rating?

Comment: I don't know, where can I find it? It's a pc power supply. It's strange because when there is power drain, buzz disappears

Comment: On the label, datasheet, manufacturers web site. Why would you want to run it with no load anyway?

Comment: Because I leave the power supply connected to monitor and, when monitor is off, it is connected with no load

Comment: ....and they normally deliver most of it through the 5V output.

Comment: But my pc doesn't buzz when it is off... So why should the monitor's power supply do it?

Comment: I mean: the power supply I use in my pc doesn't buzz when there is no load (because pc is off) so why should the power supply connected to monitor buzz? Shouldn't the minimum loads be the same?

Comment: Looking in internet I found that could be a capacitor problem. Could it be?

Comment: When the PC is off its PSU switches to a special standby mode. It still has a load, just a very small one.

Comment: I understand. So is there a way to stop the buzz?

Comment: Yes, ensure it always has a minimum load connected. Which leads you back to my first comment.

Comment: Ok. How can I do it? With a resistor?

Comment: Yes, once you find what the minimum load should be. Or be prepared to use trial and error, probably starting somewhere around 0.1A

Comment: I only found this http://microdream.co.uk/media/catalog/product/i/m/img_2143_4.jpg and that the monitor controller's consumption is 0,5W in stand-by

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When load is low or very light, most SMPS will either reduce the frequency, or work in skip-cycle mode.

Skip-cycle mode is a clever way to save power: the very light load slowly discharges the output capacitor. When voltage reaches a lower threshold, the supply pumps a few switching cycles to recharge it, then goes back to sleep.

When the frequency of this event is in the audible range, then what you hear will be:

- A ceramic capacitor acting piezoelectric
- Magnetostriction or other "voice coil" effects in the transformer

You can add a load at the output (a resistor) to shift the frequency to an inaudible one.

An alternate solution can be to put some insulating viscoelastic caulk on the noisy components (ie, polyurethane, but not water-based acrylic). But if it's the transformer, there's not much you can do...